# How to pause the game in Screen libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Sorry for my question , but i am  stuck. I am new in develop game with lib gdx and don`t judge me strictly.
I have my game activity:

```
public class MyGame extends Game {
MenuScreen menu;
SplashScreen splash;
DefendScreen def;

@Override
public void create() {
    // Gdx.app.log("LogGame", "MyGame create");
    menu = new MenuScreen(this);
    splash = new SplashScreen(this);
    def = new DefendScreen(this);
    setScreen(splash);


}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    super.pause();

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    super.resume();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

I have two screens :

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {
public MenuScreen(final MyGame gam) {
    game = gam;
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    defScreen = new DefendScreen(game);
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage();
}
@Override
public void dispose() {
    Gdx.app.log("LogGame", "splashs dispose");
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);

    try {

        spriteBatch.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
        font12.dispose();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void pause() {



}
@Override
public void render(float arg0) {
    SetCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2f);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(); // update all actors
    stage.draw();

}
@Override
public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void show() {
    stage.addActor(new WorldMenu(new Texture(Gdx.files
            .internal("images/bg/pause_back.png"))));

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(
            Gdx.files.internal("font/trebuchet_ms.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 25;
    font12 = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();

    DrawLeftMeu();
    DrawRightMeu();
    DrawSetingsMenu();

}}
```

And game screen  where i have pause button:

```
public class DefendScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {
public DefendScreen(final MyGame gam) {
    game = gam;
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
    startTime = TimeUtils.millis();
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

    stage = new Stage();
    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

}
@Override
public void dispose() {
    Gdx.app.log("LogGame", "defend dispose");
    try {
        combo0.dispose();
        combo1.dispose();
        combo2.dispose();
        good0.dispose();
        good1.dispose();
        bad0.dispose();
        bad1.dispose();
        bad2.dispose();
        bad3.dispose();
        bad4.dispose();
        music.dispose();
        music.stop();
        spriteBatch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
        pbar.dispose();
        scores.dispose();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
@Override
public void hide() {
}

@Override
public void pause() {

    // this.state = State.PAUSE;
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    SetCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2f);
    switch (state) {
    case RUN:
        RunGame();
        break;
    case PAUSE:
        // do stuff here

        break;
    case RESUME:

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
@Override
public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    this.state = State.RESUME;
}

@Override
public void show() {

    regions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    addRegions();
    initSounds();
    speedgame = speedgameEasy;

    stage.addActor(worldActor);
    stage.addActor(pauseActor);
    startTime = TimeUtils.millis();

    stage.addListener(clickList);

    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(
            Gdx.files.internal("font/trebuchet_ms.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 25;
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();

    pbar = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/bg/line_indicator.png"));
    scores = new Texture(
            Gdx.files.internal("images/game_images/scorebox.png"));

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
}}
```

And my main questions !!! 
--> what i must do that on pause action i can freeze the game action and call menu screen (whish have button resume)?
--> what i mus do in resume onclick to show game action  resume?
on stackoverflow an other forums i find some explains about my question, which means to implement in resume some switch case with choices of game state, but i am do not understand how its realize in my code.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Use `game.setScreen(game.menu);`. And to go back to the game use `game.setScreen(game.def);`.

Comment: in onClick method i must call something like game.pause() or this.pause() | game.resume()
because when i do  game.setScreen(game.menu); and game.setScreen(game.def); my game start fron begin not resume

Comment: That's happening because you have the initialization code in the `show` methods of your screens. You should move that code to the class constructor. The `show` method is called by the `game.setScreen` method, so the `show` method should only contain stuff that you want to happen every time the screen reappears..

Comment: The switch statement you're using for game states including PAUSE and RESUME doesn't make sense. RESUME isn't a state, but rather an event (actually semantically, neither is PAUSE and it should instead be called PAUSED). In your case, since you simply want to switch to the menu screen, you can remove the switch statement entirely because you always simply want the game to be running when this screen is active.

Comment: By the way, your Game's `resize` method should be calling `super.resize`.

Answer (score -3):

In your game screen you should have a button (an actor added to the stage) which implements a ClickListener that calls either `pause()` or `resume()` depending on the current state of the game.

It should look something like this:

```
pauseButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent evt, float x, float y) {
            if (!paused) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener().pause();
            else Gdx.app.getApplicationListener().resume();
        }
    });
```

Where `paused` is a boolean variable  in your game screen class.

In my opinion this is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: nononononoononnoo `pause()` and `resume()` are event callbacks of LibGDX, don't call them directly!

Comment: My bad, in that case you should simply call `MyGame.pause()` which should normally call the `pause()` method of the currently active screen.

Comment: Actually it should be `Gdx.app.getApplicationListener().pause();`

Comment: That's even worse. The whole point is that you need to implement the pause and resume logic elsewhere, as the pause/resume of LibGDX are to halt the music and stuff, maybe even serialize the game state to ensure that no data is lost, not just to pause the game logic itself. `pause()` and `resume()` are called when the activity `onPause()` and `onResume()` are called, and ought to be implemented as such.

Comment: and actualy what i must do ?
if i correctly  understand i must in my DefScreen on payse bt click listener do pause() and open MenuScreen, and in menu screen i must call resume and setScreenDefScreen ? wright?

Comment: Never call any of Libgdx's pause and resume methods directly. Those are used by the engine for suspending the application when it goes into the background. It is up to you to come up with whatever method of game-pausing you want to do, but of course you will have to name the method something other than `pause` because Libgdx is already using that for application suspension.